# Add another page to my Glassfish server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, glassfish, webserver

I have a glassfish web app running, and I want to add another page to my server. The page will not be static. The problem I have is mapping the page. I do know that (maybe?) I need to add servlets into my web.xml file for them to run validation and have access to a database? If that's true, how does the servlet communicate with the jsp?
Much help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following codes in your `web.xml` file
  you can use any name in the `<servlet-name>` but it must match with 
the `<servlet- mapping>` tag `<servlet-name >`
here i am using  `<jsp-file >` for including  jsp file  you can use

```
 <servlet-class>mysite.server.TeamServlet</servlet-class>
```

for class file

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jsp1</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/WEB-INF/myjsp/jsp1.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jsp1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/jsp1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is for a static page though, right?